# Messed up with deploy key

Tags: github, ssh, deployment, key, git-push

When I try to push my files to the git server I faced this problem.
`~ git push
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

So, I've entered `git push --set-upstream origin main` in the terminal. It was showing up the following error.

`ERROR: Permission to adivenkat05/C-Assignments.git denied to deploy key`
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

So, after searching for the solution, it was that we need to upload our ssh key in the git server (Deploy Key).

I've uploaded that same key to another repository but it ended up showing me this "So, after searching for the solution, it was that we need to upload our ssh key in the git server (Deploy Key).

I've uploaded that same key to another repository but it ended up showing me this "Key is already in use".

So, it's not possible to have multiple ssh keys in a particular machine, right?

How do I tackle this problem?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error is different, and refer to an authentication problem.

You can have multiple keys, a deploy one and one [associated with your user account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Create a new dedicated key, and [add it to your account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/me
```

Reference it in a `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And your SSH URL becomes `gh:me/myRepository`.  (no more `git@github.com:...`)
You can test your SSH key with `ssh -Tv gh`.

It it works:

```bash
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote set-url origin gh:adivenkat05/C-Assignments.git
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: why gh:me and not just gh?  If I created an identity file named ~/.ssh/notme, would  the URL be gh:notme?

Comment: @MichaelTuchman Not `gh:me`, but `gh:me/myRepo`. The `gh` part if for authentication to `github.com` through the `~/.ssh/me` private SSH key, the `me/myRepo` part if for referencing the repository to which origin points to.